# Gameboy Emulator pop off empty stack

Tags: emulation, gameboy

I'm working on a Gameboy Emulator, and I've reached a point in the ROM where I get opcode `0xD1` (pop `DE` off stack) but the stack is empty (no values have been pushed onto it). All unknown opcodes return an error, and all other instructions seem to be working fine.

Is it an error in my programming, the ROM, or is this just a quick way for the program to set `DE` to `0x0000`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if no value has been `PUSH`ed to the stack, `POP` will retrieve the value stored at the address in `SP` to the specified register pair, and `SP` will be incremented by `2`.

In your example, if `SP` has been initialized to, say `wD000`, and that the WRAM is initialized to `0` beforehand, `POP DE` would effectively load `0` to `DE`, and increment the `Stack Pointer` by `2`.

```
21 00 C0         ld   hl,C000       ;Start of WRAM
01 FF 1F         ld   bc,1FFF       ;Length of WRAM
AF               xor  a             ;a = 0
22               ldi  (hl),a        ;Blanks WRAM
0B               dec  bc
78               ld   a,b
B1               or   c
20 F9            jr   nz,0158       ;Loops until WRAM is cleared
21 00 D0         ld   hl,D000
F9               ld   sp,hl         ;SP = 0xD000
D1               pop  de            ;de = 0x0000, SP = 0xD002
```

Also, please note that the `CALL` instruction pushes the return address to the stack, and decrements `SP` by `2`. In the same way, `RET` retrieves the address from the stack, and increases `SP` by `2`.

Comment: Thank you, clear and concise answer that solved my problem!